# ImageJ jar file plugin shortcut creation - More help needed

Tags: javascript, imagej

I've been trying to automate cell counting on ImageJ/Fiji using an plugin called ITCN.  This problem has come up on the forum before ([ImageJ jar file plugin shortcut creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791072/imagej-jar-file-plugin-shortcut-creation/4797197#4797197)) and I am having the same unresolved problem.

If I code a script using javascript as follows:

```
imp = IJ.getImage();

IJ.run(imp, "Invert", "");
IJ.run(imp, "16-bit", "");
IJ.run(imp, "8-bit", "");
IJ.run(imp, "Median...", "radius=2");

runner = new ITCN_Runner( imp,
                          11, /* width*/
                          5.5, /* minimum distance */
                          0.7, /* threshold */
                          true, /* detect dark peaks */
                          null /* mask ImagePlus */ )
runner.run()
```

then I get the error message:

```
ReferenceError: "ITCN_Runner" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#8) in <Unknown source> at line number 8
```

I am very (VERY!) new to programming and Fiji.  So I am not quite sure what the problem is.  Does anyone have any comments or suggestions?

Thanks so much for your help!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Your are just missing to import the ITCN_Runner class at the very beginning of your Javascript:

```
importClass(Packages.ITCN_Runner);
```

(provided that [ITCN_1_6_.jar](http://www.bioimage.ucsb.edu/downloads/automatic-nuclei-counter-plug-in-for-imagej) is in your classpath, e.g. in `./Fiji.app/plugins/`)

See the [Javascript scripting documentation](http://fiji.sc/Javascript_Scripting#Importing_packages_and_classes) for more help.