# Unable to use ITCN_Runner through javascript (Possible Bug in the Plugin)

Tags: javascript, java, plugins, jar, imagej

I am trying to use the ITCN plugin for counting the number of nuclie in my image using javascripts supported in ImageJ environment. My old (ImageJ 1.49xx) javascript no longer work because everything has been changed to Java 8 compiler for ImageJ1.51xx.  With the help of this post, (http://forum.imagej.net/t/itcn-threshold-option-missing/1095/3) and this ([ImageJ jar file plugin shortcut creation - More help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997613/imagej-jar-file-plugin-shortcut-creation-more-help-needed)) I have made some progress.

Here is a simple example code:-

```
  //importing the requisite packages
  importClass(Packages.ij.ImagePlus);
  importClass(Packages.ITCN_Runner);

  var filename = 'Path/to/8bit/single/channel/.tiff/file'

  //make a ImagePlus object

  var imp = new ImagePlus(fileName);                             

   //Call ITCN_runner to generate results window 

   var runner = new ITCN_Runner( imp,
    24, /* width*/
    12, /* minimum distance */
    0.5, /* threshold */
    false, /* detect dark peaks */
    null /* mask ImagePlus */ )
```

When I run the above script, I run into the following error:-

```
    TypeError: new cannot be used with non-public java type ITCN_Runner.
      at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
   Followed by several lines...
```

My guess is that this is caused because the ITCN_Runner.class in the ITCN_.jar does not specify the class ITCN_Runner as public. This was alright in Java6  but is no longer allowed in Java 8 it seems.

Should the ITCN_Runner.class have been declared as public by the source builder? Or I am making a mistake here. How can I fix this problem.

Any suggestions or workarounds welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a very non ideal workaround that I came up with for the above problem. So instead of setting up a ITCN_Runner, I have removed the following lines

```
var runner = new ITCN_Runner( imp,
24, /* width*/
12, /* minimum distance */
0.5, /* threshold */
false, /* detect dark peaks */
null /* mask ImagePlus */ )
```

and replaced them with run command to start the ITCN plugin itself

```
 IJ.run("ITCN ", "")

    new WaitForUserDialog("Get the results from ITCN",
        "Please press OK when done with ITCN.").show();
```

The WaitForUserDialog waits for me to manually generate the results window, exit out of the plugin and capture the results for writting into a csv as follows.

```
//////Time Delay function//////
    var tp = IJ.getTextPanel();
        while ( tp.getLineCount() < 2 ) {
            IJ.wait(500);
            }
////Parsing Results///  
    //var fileName = tp.getLine(0);
    var DAPI = tp.getLine(1);
    tp.clear();
```

Any suggestions to improve this will be a great help.

Thanks 
lune3141